# Prestashop - Error when select a product

Tags: prestashop

I'm developing a prestashop store and when I select a product in products list it returns me this error `Undefined index: delivery_information`:

```
    ContextErrorException in e42bf994e1c52b1889de74854b0c1c6e154cca51.file.product.tpl.php line 941:
Notice: Undefined index: delivery_information
in e42bf994e1c52b1889de74854b0c1c6e154cca51.file.product.tpl.php line 941
at ErrorHandler->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: delivery_information', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lojateste/app/cache/dev/smarty/compile/layouts_layout_full_width_tpl/e4/2b/f9/e42bf994e1c52b1889de74854b0c1c6e154cca51.file.product.tpl.php', '941', array('_smarty_tpl' => object(Smarty_Dev_Template))) in e42bf994e1c52b1889de74854b0c1c6e154cca51.file.product.tpl.php line 941
at content_5a3af02764f156_81278853(object(Smarty_Dev_Template)) in e42bf994e1c52b1889de74854b0c1c6e154cca51.file.product.tpl.php line 285
at content_5a3af027dc2ef5_57772788(object(Smarty_Dev_Template)) in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 188
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('catalog/product.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', null, false, true, false) in SmartyDev.php line 41
at SmartyDev->fetch('catalog/product.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl') in FrontController.php line 671
at FrontControllerCore->smartyOutputContent('catalog/product.tpl') in FrontController.php line 655
at FrontControllerCore->display() in Controller.php line 225
at ControllerCore->run() in Dispatcher.php line 379
at DispatcherCore->dispatch() in index.php line 28
```

I go to this temporary file and the problem is in this lines:

```
public function display()
{
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'layout' => $this->getLayout(),
        'stylesheets' => $this->getStylesheets(),
        'javascript' => $this->getJavascript(),
        'js_custom_vars' => Media::getJsDef(),
        'notifications' => $this->prepareNotifications(),
    ));

    $this->smartyOutputContent($this->template);

    return true;
}

protected function smartyOutputContent($content)
{
    $this->context->cookie->write();

    $html = '';

    if (is_array($content)) {
        foreach ($content as $tpl) {
            $html .= $this->context->smarty->fetch($tpl, null, $this->getLayout());
        }
    } else {
        $html = $this->context->smarty->fetch($content, null, $this->getLayout());
    }

    Hook::exec('actionOutputHTMLBefore',  array('html' => &$html));
    echo trim($html);
}
```

I try to clean cache, I check if there is any needed information in product but I think not.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Which PS version are you using?

Comment: The problem is in the `product.tpl` - you're trying to access `delivery_information` which is not defined